# Alignat, but starting at the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I need something that behaves exactly as the alignat environment. However, I also need the text to start at the left. Is there anything that would work?

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&k_1     &&\geq 1 \quad\land \quad &&k_1     \leq a_1      \\
&k_2     &&\geq 1 \quad\land \quad &&k_2     \leq a_2      \\
&\qquad \cdots \\
&k_{n-1} &&\geq 1 \quad\land &&k_{n-1} \leq a_{n-1}  \\
&k_n     &&\geq 1 \quad\land &&k_n     \leq a_n      \quad \}
\end{alignat*}
```

I need all the text inside the alignat* starting at the left side.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Which text? Before alignat? Please specify your question a little bit.

Comment: You might nest the internal form `alignedat` within `flalign`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

with `fleqn` environment from the package `nccmath` and use of `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}    % <---

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\[
    \setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
    \begin{array}{lcccl}
k_1     & \geq 1 & \land & k_1     & \leq a_1      \\
k_2     & \geq 1 & \land & k_2     & \leq a_2      \\
\vdots  &        &       &         &               \\
k_{n-1} & \geq 1 & \land & k_{n-1} & \leq a_{n-1}  \\
k_n     & \geq 1 & \land & k_n     & \leq a_n
    \end{array}
\]
or
\[
    \setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
    \begin{array}{rcccl}
k_1     & \geq 1 & \land & k_1     & \leq a_1      \\
k_2     & \geq 1 & \land & k_2     & \leq a_2      \\
\vdots  &        &       &         &               \\
k_{n-1} & \geq 1 & \land & k_{n-1} & \leq a_{n-1}  \\
k_n     & \geq 1 & \land & k_n     & \leq a_n
    \end{array}
\]
or
\[
    \setlength\arraycolsep{1.5pt}
    \begin{array}{rccl}
k_1     & \geq 1 & \land & k_1      \leq a_1      \\
k_2     & \geq 1 & \land & k_2      \leq a_2      \\
\vdots  &        &       &                        \\
k_{n-1} & \geq 1 & \land & k_{n-1}  \leq a_{n-1}  \\
k_n     & \geq 1 & \land & k_n      \leq a_n
    \end{array}
\]
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the requirement to start at the left margin. Anyway, the alignment is better done with `array`.

The `lipsum` package is used just to provide context and show the alignment as if it appeared in a real document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[4]
\begin{flalign*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{
  c
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  c
  @{\quad}c@{\quad} % for \land
  c
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  c
}
k_1     & \geq & 1 & \land & k_1     & \leq & a_1      \\
k_2     & \geq & 1 & \land & k_2     & \leq & a_2      \\
        &      &   & \vdots \\
k_{n-1} & \geq & 1 & \land & k_{n-1} & \leq & a_{n-1}  \\
k_n     & \geq & 1 & \land & k_n     & \leq & a_n
\end{array}
&&
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]